# In Excel trying to update rows in Sheet 1 from Sheet 2 based on a unique id found in both sheets

Tags: excel, vba

My question is similar to some found on this forum, but I can't quite get it to work. I have a master sheet in excel that has all my data with many columns and rows. What happens is, I receive updated data via excel sheets and need to update the master sheet based on a unique id, that is found in both sheets. Not all cells will have new data, so I would like to only update cells that have changed.

What I have found so far works, but it isn't updating all the cells. I'm new to VBA, so any help would be greatly appreciated. If this code is not what I should be doing then I'm willing to scrap it and start from scratch.

Here is the code that I found on this forum, but I can't quite get it to do what I need. I have tried changing it slightly, but to no avail. I have included the code as it appears in the forum. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
Dim sh1 As Worksheet
    Dim rw2 As Range

    Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    For Each rw2 In Sheets("Sheet2").UsedRange.Rows
      If Not sh1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(rw2.Cells(1, 2).Value,, xlValues, xlWhole) Is Nothing Then
        rw2.Cells(1, 5) = sh1.UsedRange.Columns(1).Find(rw2.Cells(1, 2).Value,, xlValues, xlWhole).Offset(0, 6)
      End If
    Next rw2
```

Comment: If you can post an image of the data format in imgur and then link it in the comments, I will help you. I don't understand exactly how your formats are setup, if the master sheet is a separate workbook, etc. What the linked code is doing is searching Sheet1 column A for each row of Sheet2 column "B". If it finds it, it's updating column E with the value from sheet 1. I'm not sure if this is what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

this doesnt need a VBA macro unless its a multitude of files.

Use a formula:

```
=index(table,match(variables, array, 0),match(variables, array, 0))
```

if its the same process everytime use this is my personal code for a similar task. Just adjust the formula, worksheet, ranges.

```
Dim kcFormula As String

kcFormula = "=IF(OR(Table3[[#This Row],[Status]]=" & """Rejected""" & "," & "Table3[[#This Row],[Status]] =" & """Completed""" & "," & "Table3[[#This Row],[Status]]=" & """Not Implemented""" & ")," & """ """ & ",INDEX('AMLLAST'!$1:$1048576,MATCH(Table3[[#This Row],[ID]],'AMLLAST'!$E:$E,0),11))"
lastROW = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
With Sheets("AML")
myRNG = "K2:" & "K" & lastROW
            Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).NumberFormat = "General"
            Sheets("AML").Range(myRNG).Formula = kcFormula
End With
```

Comment: show me and imagine i can write you a quick formula if thats whats necessary.